# TeamCity error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I'm trying to configure Git as a VCS for TeamCity 7.1.2.

When running a build, I'm seeing the following error:

> jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.VcsException: 'git fetch' command failed.
>   exception: Cannot run program "c:\TeamCity\jre\bin\java" (in directory "C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\system\caches\git\git-5BB95C96.git"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

If I cd to that path in a terminal on the build server and attempt to run the referenced java binary, it runs properly.

The full stack trace is:

```
jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.VcsException: 'git fetch' command failed. 
exception: Cannot run program "c:\TeamCity\jre\bin\java" (in directory "C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\system\caches\git\git-5BB95C96.git"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application 
    at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.CommandLineUtil.getCommandLineError(CommandLineUtil.java:44)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.FetchCommandImpl.fetchInSeparateProcess(FetchCommandImpl.java:132)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.FetchCommandImpl.fetch(FetchCommandImpl.java:70) 
    at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.GitVcsSupport.fetch(GitVcsSupport.java:391) 
    at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.GitVcsSupport.fetch(GitVcsSupport.java:407) 
    at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.GitVcsSupport.fetchBranchData(GitVcsSupport.java:377) 
    at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.GitVcsSupport.ensureRevCommitLoaded(GitVcsSupport.java:246)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.GitVcsSupport.buildPatch(GitVcsSupport.java:216) 
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.projectSources.BuildPatchUtil.buildPatch(BuildPatchUtil.java:1)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.projectSources.PatchComposer.buildCleanPatchToStream(PatchComposer.java:115)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.projectSources.PatchComposer.access$100(PatchComposer.java:104)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.projectSources.PatchComposer$2.constructPatch(PatchComposer.java:1)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.projectSources.SmallPatchCache.getCachedCleanPatch(SmallPatchCache.java:12)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.projectSources.PatchCacheImpl.requestCachedPatch(PatchCacheImpl.java:5)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.projectSources.PatchComposer.getOrMakeCacheableCleanPatch(PatchComposer.java:153)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.projectSources.PatchComposer.makePatch(PatchComposer.java:141)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.projectSources.PatchComposer.buildPatchForRoot(PatchComposer.java:46)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.projectSources.PatchComposer.buildPatch(PatchComposer.java:0)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.BuildTypeImpl.buildPatch(BuildTypeImpl.java:59) 
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.BuildStarter$2.call(BuildStarter.java:4) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can anyone suggest something to try?

Comment: This might be relevant: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/f33aca2a-074d-4f12-85d4-946bd11965cc

Comment: Duplicate is here: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5488746